# HTML parsing to TextView (Swift 4 issue)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

HtmlString = `<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td>as</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>a</td><td> </td><td> </td><td>a</td></tr></tbody></table>`

I have extension on string which parse string (html) to NSAttributedString.

On swift 3:

```
guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }

guard let htmlString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
    data: data,
    options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
    documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }

let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: htmlString.length);
    htmlString.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, in: fullRange, options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, using: {
        (attributes, range, stop) -> Void in

        let newFont = UIFont.preferredFont(fontName: FontName.kHelveticaNeueLight, fontSize: FontSize.kTextView);
        htmlString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: newFont, range: range);
    });

    htmlString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value:Color.kGrayDark, range:fullRange)

return htmlString;
```

And on swift 4:

```
    guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
    guard let htmlString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
        documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
    let fullRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: htmlString.length);

    htmlString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, in: fullRange, options: NSAttributedString.EnumerationOptions.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, using: {
        (attributes, range, stop) -> Void in
        let newFont = UIFont(name: FontName.regular.value, size: FontSize.html)
        htmlString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: newFont ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: FontSize.html), range: range);
    });

    htmlString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value:UIColor.html(), range:fullRange)
    return htmlString;
```

Swift 3 Results:

[image]

Swift 4 Results:

[image]

I miss border on Swift 4. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistake was because I used Label for attributedText instead TextView. It works great with textView.

Answer (score 0):

sizing on UILabel attributedString in html will have funnies if accessibility font is different than default. Test on ios 11.2 and you will spot them